# Dealing with ampersand and special characters in SQL

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to transform legacy data into a new properly structured SQL DB. For simplicity, lets say an old table contains two fields, Id and Emails. Here is some data.

```
ID | Emails  
0 test@test.com, test1@test.com, stuff@domain.com  
1 thing@thing.com
```

I want to bring them into the new table like so:

```
ID | Emails  
0 test@test.com  
0 test1@test.com  
0 stuff@domain.com  
1 thing@thing.com
```

I can do this with this TSQL:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable(Id, [Address])
Select t.Id, split.val
From OldTable t
Cross Apply dbo.Split(t.Emails, ',') split
WHERE t.Emails <> ''
```

This works well until I run into an email that has a special character in it like so:
email@tom&jerry.com

The ampersand breaks the query and throws the following error:
*Msg 9411, Level 16, State 1, Line 3

XML parsing: line 1, character 27, semicolon expected*

What is the easiest way to circumvent the error and map the email into the new table as is: email@tom&jerry.com

Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with the version of the database that you're using.  If it is SQL Server, what implementation of `dbo.Split` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just simply use the replace initially to replace all ampersands with something else, say "AANNDD" or '>>AND<<'.

```
SELECT REPLACE(Emails, '&', '>>AND<<')...
```

Then just replace that back after you're done.

You could just replace all amperands in your old table before the insert.  Then just run the update on your new table.

Comment: Yeah. I can replace '&' with '&amp;' and that works well. I was just wondering if there is a best practice for something like this. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest way is the best.

Comment: @BBauer42 - Best practice would be to use an implementation of `Split` that is better behaved.  It should split on the supplied separator and, optionally, have a provision for handling quoted strings.  Otherwise, it shouldn't trip up on common characters.